Django static files 404 errors just for one folder and all images
Edit
The syntax error fix provided by willeM_ Van Onsem fixed the addition of characters to the path of the image. Now they are just normal 404 errors :).
And with those fixed, python returns more 404 errors so I see that there is nothing unique about the daterangepicker folder

Original
I'm integrating a theme into my project. Some of the static files are found, but I get two types 404 errors.  I'd appreciate any help.
The first type (all images):
For the line
<img class="rounded-circle" src="{% static 'sleek-bootstrap/source/assets/img/user/u6.jpg" alt="Image' %}">

I get the error
"GET /static/sleek-bootstrap/source/assets/img/user/u6.jpg%22%20alt%3D%22Image 404 1958

The file /static/sleek-bootstrap/source/assets/img/user/u6.jpg does exist, but somehow Django adds %22%20alt%3D%22Image to the name, so of course it can't find it. It does this for all the image files in the template
The second type (one folder):
for the line
    <script src="{% static 'sleek-bootstrap/source/assets/plugins/daterangepicker/moment.min.js' %}"> ></script>

I get the error
"GET /static/sleek-bootstrap/source/assets/plugins/daterangepicker/moment.min.js HTTP/1.1" HTTP/1.1" 404 1958
Django finds all the files in the path /static/sleek-bootstrap/source/assets/plugins/, except those in the daterangepicker plugin folder.

You closed to template tag too late:
<img class="rounded-circle" src="{% static 'sleek-bootstrap/source/assets/img/user/u6.jpg" %} alt="Image">
By using {% static 'some-img" alt="text' %}"', you included the alt=` attribute in the name of the file, and this then returns a 404.
